# Instagram embed post not working on wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, instagram

When I try to embed an instagram post I get the message unexpected json response.

`<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>`

This is the last line of the embed code, and when I remove it it works, but then instead of the picture it display the 'view on instagram' text.

Adding http:// to the link doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't support unsigned Instagram embeds anymore, due to the changes in Instagram API: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/09/22/facebook-and-instagram-embeds-to-be-deprecated-october-24th/

Above thread suggests to use `oEmbed Plus` plugin to workaround this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/oembed-plus/

Comment: Thnak you I didn't know about this!